# Camel - Making parallel GET requests and aggregating the results via Dynamic Routes using Java DSL

Tags: rest, apache-camel, jetty

I am receiving a request on a Jetty Http Endpoint. The request body contains some urls in the request body. I have to make a `GET` request to those urls. Then aggregate the results from each of the `GET` request and return it to the caller.

Request Body:-

```
{
    "data" : [
        {"name" : "Hello", "url" : "http://server1"}
        {"name" : "Hello2", "url" : "http://server2"}

    ]
}
```

One way I can think of doing this is like below:-

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/hello").process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // 1. Make the GET request in parallel using ThreadPoolExecutor
        // 2. Wait for all calls to finish. Collate the response
        // 3. Write it to exchange.getOut().setBody
    }
})
```

Can some one let me know if this can be achieved via Java DSL using camel Dynamic Routes, Splitter & Aggregator so that the `Processor` remains relatively small?

I am using camel 2.16.3.

Comment: Conceptually, you could split the original message so that each new message has a single URL. Those split requests can go through some processor. After that, you could place an aggregator. I guess multiple messages can come in to the initial consumer, so you need to figure out how to identify what URLs belong to what URL-group.

Comment: Are you suggesting from the processor I should make the HTTP call or connecting the processor with some `to()` ?

Comment: Not necessarily. I framed it that way because your example showed a processor doing the GETs. You could use one of the Camel components: http, http4, or even cxfrs or spring-ws, ... whichever fits your needs with the least complexity.

Comment: Since the url is in the request body that is coming at jetty endpoint. Can you let me know how can I add the url in http4 component after the splitter? Since the url is quite dynamic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps would be:

1. Split the incoming data into URLs. This might involve sub-steps: for
   instance, you might unmarshal the incoming JSON string into some POJO and perhaps this POJO has an array or list where each entry is a URL. Then, you could pass this along as the body. (Of course, you might need other information from the incoming request, so you might vary this.)
2. The splitter would split easily enough if the body is a Array or something else that it can handle easily. In the simplest case, the splitter would pass on a single URI in the body of each split message.
3. Next -- within the splitter's flow -- you could have a producer like http4, but instead of using the URI on the endpoint, you could ask it to use the URI in the message.
4. Finally, you would have an aggregator.

Sounds like the core of your question is about the dynamic URI. This is how a code-snippet might look:

```
 from(...)... etc. 
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("${body}"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,  
              constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.GET))
    .to("http4://google.com")
```

For a small work-demo, [see this class](https://github.com/DariusX/CamelSandbox/blob/master/CamelSandbox/src/main/java/com/zerses/camelsandbox/ws/HttpDynamicClient.java).

```
public class HttpDynamicClient extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:testMultiple")
        .split(body())
        .to("direct:httpClient");

        from("direct:httpClient")
        .log("starting httpClient route")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("${body}"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.GET))
        .to("http4://google.com")
        .process(new BodyToStringConverter())
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Output was ${body}");
    }

    private static class BodyToStringConverter implements Processor {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HttpDynamicClient.class);

            context.addRoutes(new HttpDynamicClient());
            ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);


            template.sendBody("direct:httpClient", "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            template.sendBody("direct:testMultiple", new String [] {"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" , "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"});


        } finally {
            context.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks !!. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @Darius X. is pretty much what you need. To make the backend requests execute in parallel and to aggregate the response bodies in a string list you need to setup an aggregation strategy and set the parallel processing flag on the split definition.

```java
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("direct:testMultiple")
            .split(body(), new FlexibleAggregationStrategy<String>()
                    .pick(Builder.body())
                    .castAs(String.class)
                    .accumulateInCollection(ArrayList.class))
            .parallelProcessing()
            // .executorService(<instance of java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService>) // optional: use custom thread pool for parallel processing
            .to("direct:httpClient");

    from("direct:httpClient")
            .log("starting httpClient route")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("${body}"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.GET))
            .to("http4://google.com")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Output was ${body}");
}
```

The out message of the exchange returned by `direct:testMultiple` will contain your result array as body.